# How to proceed to debug a react native app?

Tags: android, debugging, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, react-native-navigation

I am facing issues with my react native app and I don't know how to proceed to debug it.

I passed my time to fix mismatch between: the different versions of the packages I am using, the different upgrades/updates (packages, react native, Android Studio etc.), the dependencies more than actually code or correct my code.

It's really frustrating and I feel like I do it wrong or something to stay stuck that much with these kind of problems.

Here the informations I have concerning my current issue:

I have **Messages Build Gradle**:

[image]

**The logcat:**

```
                                                   --------- beginning of system
08-02 14:10:03.784 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-02 14:10:03.784 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-02 14:10:03.813 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
08-02 14:12:03.754 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-02 14:12:03.754 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-02 14:12:03.796 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
08-02 14:12:13.757 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-02 14:12:13.758 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
08-02 14:12:13.800 758-793/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
08-02 14:34:43.308 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:34:43.328 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:34:43.347 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:34:43.947 237-329/? E/agps: [agps] ERR: [AGPS] update_imsi_to_supl_swip  IMSI is invalid
08-02 14:34:43.979 237-344/? E/agps: [agps] ERR: [SUPL_CONN_ADP] is_socket_valid  socket_fds[s]=-1 is invalid
08-02 14:34:43.980 237-344/? E/agps: [agps] ERR: [SUPL_CONN_ADP] soc_close  s=0 is invalid
08-02 14:34:45.481 758-7252/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
08-02 14:34:45.481 758-7252/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(66667000)m, error(0), index(2)
08-02 14:34:52.228 249-395/? E/epo: mtk_gps_epo_file_update: Update EPOHAL.DAT error
08-02 14:34:58.495 14056-14056/? E/PQ: [PQ][PQWhiteList] libwlparser.so is absent
08-02 14:35:02.268 249-395/? E/epo: mtk_gps_epo_file_update: Update EPOHAL.DAT error
08-02 14:35:04.818 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:04.819 249-405/? E/MNLD: fsm_gps_state_started: fsm_gps_state_started() data1=1,data2=0,data3=0x0
08-02 14:35:04.819 249-405/? E/MNLD: fsm_gps_state_started: fsm_gps_state_stopping() unexpected event=3
08-02 14:35:04.846 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:04.890 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:04.928 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:04.957 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:04.996 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:05.026 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:05.051 758-758/? E/PermissionMonitor: can't find permission:android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE
08-02 14:35:05.051 758-758/? E/PermissionMonitor: can't find permission:android.permission.CONNECTIVITY_INTERNAL
08-02 14:35:05.055 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:05.081 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:05.112 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:05.141 758-1116/? E/CellLocation: create GsmCellLocation
08-02 14:35:05.145 249-396/? E/qepo: is_quarter_epo_valid: Read QEPO file failed
08-02 14:35:05.148 758-1116/? E/GnssLocationProvider: Error getting cell location info.
08-02 14:35:05.530 14127-14127/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
08-02 14:35:05.647 237-329/? E/agps: [agps] ERR: [AGPS] update_imsi_to_supl_swip  IMSI is invalid
08-02 14:35:05.670 237-344/? E/agps: [agps] ERR: [SUPL_CONN_ADP] is_socket_valid  socket_fds[s]=-1 is invalid
08-02 14:35:05.671 237-344/? E/agps: [agps] ERR: [SUPL_CONN_ADP] soc_close  s=0 is invalid
08-02 14:35:05.768 3794-14020/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
08-02 14:35:05.768 3794-14020/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
08-02 14:35:05.783 3794-14018/? E/MPlugin: Unsupported class: com.mediatek.common.telephony.IOnlyOwnerSimSupport
08-02 14:35:05.789 3810-8754/? E/Drive.UninstallOperation: Package still installed com.accessidico
08-02 14:35:05.977 12587-12587/? E/Finsky: [1] com.google.android.finsky.wear.bl.a(847): onConnectionFailed: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
08-02 14:35:06.296 3794-14020/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid parameter app
08-02 14:35:06.296 3794-14020/? E/NetworkScheduler.SR: Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
08-02 14:35:11.977 249-405/? E/MNLD: fsm_gps_state_started: fsm_gps_state_started() data1=0,data2=0,data3=0x0
08-02 14:35:12.026 249-405/? E/MNLD: fsm_gps_state_stopping: fsm_gps_state_stopping() data1=0,data2=0,data3=0x0
08-02 14:35:12.356 249-395/? E/epo: mtk_gps_epo_file_update: Update EPOHAL.DAT error
08-02 14:35:16.587 14219-14219/? E/PQ: [PQ][PQWhiteList] libwlparser.so is absent
08-02 14:35:16.956 9224-13999/? E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error -4 during AudioRecord native read
08-02 14:35:17.235 758-2532/? E/Sensors: handleToDriver handle(0)
08-02 14:35:17.236 758-2532/? E/Sensors: new setDelay handle(0),ns(66667000)m, error(0), index(2)
08-02 14:35:17.470 3794-3794/? E/ActivityThread: Service com.google.android.location.places.service.PlaceDetectionAsyncService has leaked IntentReceiver amth@cdb5c40 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                 android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.google.android.location.places.service.PlaceDetectionAsyncService has leaked IntentReceiver amth@cdb5c40 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1201)
                                                     at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:951)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1314)
                                                     at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1294)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:593)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:593)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:593)
                                                     at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:593)
                                                     at amrb.run(:com.google.android.gms:4414)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
                                                     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
08-02 14:35:17.473 3794-14255/? E/Places: IllegalArgumentException whilst unregistering receiver. Was SignalManager stopped before being started?
08-02 14:35:19.818 14229-14268/? E/ReactNativeJS: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeReactModule.startApp')
08-02 14:35:19.877 14229-14268/? E/ReactNativeJS: Application AccessiDico has not been registered.

                                                  Hint: This error often happens when you're running the packager (local dev server) from a wrong folder. For example you have multiple apps and the packager is still running for the app you were working on before.
                                                  If this is the case, simply kill the old packager instance (e.g. close the packager terminal window) and start the packager in the correct app folder (e.g. cd into app folder and run 'npm start').

                                                  This error can also happen due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.



                                                  [ 08-02 14:35:19.878 14229:14280 D/         ]
                                                  [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.accessidico :8081 
08-02 14:35:22.406 249-395/? E/epo: mtk_gps_epo_file_update: Update EPOHAL.DAT error
```

And the error I get on my device (which is linked to the react-native-navigation package: https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/ ):

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeReactModule.startApp')

So I wonder, beyond my issue, what is the "checklist" to debug something like that ?

What is revelant ? What is not ?

Where should I research solutions first ?

P.S: I already followed the hint displayed in the logcat with no success.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you deleted and re-installed the `node_modules`? Sometimes that helps.

Comment: I just tried and it is still the same

Comment: I experience the same issue with the React-native-navigation - and also have no clues where to start. There is another simmilar question appearing: 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45868912/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue is because it cannot find the native module, in Android after installing the react-native-navigation package  you need to follow the following [steps](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android)