# react-native-navigation gives error "undefined is not an object"?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

```
import {
  Platform
} from 'react-native';
import {Navigation} from 'react-native-navigation';

import {registerScreens} from './screens';

registerScreens();

// this will start our app
Navigation.startSingleScreenApp({
  screen: {
    screen: 'Hiran.StartUpScreen',
    title: 'Start Screen'
  },
  animationType: 'slide-down'
});
```

my index.android.js file code is

```
__STRESS_TEST__ = false;
// import App from './src/app';
import App from './src/app_single';
```

and i am getting error as follows :

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'NativeReactModule.startApp')
startApp
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\react-native-navigation\src\platformSpecific.android.js:10:20
startSingleScreenApp
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\react-native-navigation\src\deprecated\platformSpecificDeprecated.android.js:38:31
startSingleScreenApp
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\react-native-navigation\src\Navigation.js:139:47
<unknown>
    D:\android\Hiran\src\app_single.js:12:32
loadModuleImplementation
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:174:12
guardedLoadModule
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:126:36
_require
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:110:20
<unknown>
    D:\android\Hiran\index.android.js:3
loadModuleImplementation
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:174:12
guardedLoadModule
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:119:45
_require
    D:\android\Hiran\node_modules\metro-bundler\src\Resolver\polyfills\require.js:110:20
global code
```

I guess i am missing something but don't know what using react-native-navigation first time. please help ! Thanks in advance

Comment: Same issue here while upgrading my existing project to start using the Wix navigation. When I start new app from scratch it's woking, but repeating the same steps in the existing one does not help. Might be we miss something?

    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.2",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.205",

Comment: Trying to solve this issue from last night and now i come to the point that there might be some bug in the latest react-native-navigation dependency.

Comment: I fixed it by starting new project from scratch, with react-native init and adding every line of code again...might be after some react-native package upgrade something get broken?

Comment: Okay i found the solution of my answer that if we install the react-native-navigation dependency then in android we need to follow the following instructions https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android this helps me and it works now.